# add checkbox with values from query

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to create a php web app that will have options to select using checkbox form and then submit the checkedbox to other file. but how can i do this if the value of checkbox is defined with values from query?
please help me, i cant find a solution :/

```
<form action="addPratosEnc4.php" method="POST">
        *Pratos a Adicionar:
            <select name="nomeA">
            <?php
                    try
                    {
                      $host = "xxxx";
                      $user ="xxx";
                      $password = "xxx";
                      $dbname = $user;
                      $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);
                      $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                      $sql = "SELECT nomeA FROM Disponivel;";
                      $result = $db->query($sql);
                      foreach($result as $row)
                      {
                       $nomeA = $row['nomeA'];
                       /*should be here?*/
                      }
                      $db = null;
                    }
                    catch (PDOException $e)
                    {
                      echo("<p>ERROR: {$e->getMessage()}</p>");
                    }
            ?>

            </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Disponibilizar">
        </form>
```

Comment: I don't think you can put checkboxes into a <select> block.

Comment: did php threw any error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's get this straight

- You want checkboxes, right! I mean, check!
- The nameA column is unique or primary, no duplicates!

### the logic and template together

```
<?php
try {
  $host = "xxxx";
  $user ="xxx";
  $password = "xxx";
  $dbname = $user;
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$password);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $q = "SELECT nomeA FROM Disponivel";
  $options = array();
  $count = 0;
  foreach($db->query($q) as $row) {
    $count++;
    $options[$row['nomeA']] = '<input type="checkbox" name="dispo[]" value="'.$row['nomeA'].'" />';
  }
  echo '<p>Rows processed: '.$count.'</p>';
  $db = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo '<p>ERROR: '.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
}
?>
<form action="addPratosEnc4.php" method="POST">
  *Pratos a Adicionar:
  <?php
  if (!$options) echo ' agora no hay pratos';
  else foreach ($options as $name => $input) echo '<label>'.$input.' '.$name.'</label><br />';
  ?>
  <br />
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Disponibilizar</button>
</form>
```

Try this, ask any questions if you have them and if any solutions worked for you, please mark them as answer

Comment: no checkbox appear, only this:
http://web.ist.utl.pt/ist170438/proj/addPratoToEnc4.php

Comment: ok, let me make some changes. We're gonna have to debug this so bear with me for a while

Comment: I added a row counter to the code. Please rerun in your environment and if the number of rows is `0` then there may be another underlying problem with the query or the database. I'll have to check on you later, gotta go

Comment: the result is 56, so it's not db problem :/ maybe is the way we create checkbox's

Comment: I found the error. I've been makin a lot of mistakes lately. I'll post a fix in a few mins. DONE!

Comment: I would argue that processing to foreach loops - 1 to add the options to an array and a second to write the html seems like overhead.  Yes you should try and write functions to get all the code out of html but only call it once.

Comment: @Narrim You're absolutely right, but this is not a quality code contest. The truth is that a lot of people don't handle `PHP` very well yet, so adding ideas like templating, encapsulating functionality, `DRY` practices and the like is kind of an overreach for begginers

Comment: huge thanks hanzo and all of you that try to help me :) i agree with hanzo, i dont handle php very well.. the truth is that i have so many projects with so many language at the same time, so i cant focus and really learn well one language:)
now i will handle this result in other php page, if i have any question i back:)
huge thanks again ;)

Answer (score 1):

To render the option list you do:

```
    .......
                        $nomeA = $row['nomeA'];
                        /*should be here?*/
?> <option value="<?php echo $nomeA; ?>"><?php echo $nomeA; ?></option><?php
                        }
                        $db = null;
                        }
........
```

This should create a option list within the select that is filled with the results from the query.  I assume you meant an option list not checkboxes - 
A select box gives you each option and you can only select 1.  You could also do this with radiobuttons. On the other hand you may have meant to use Checkbox's where the user can select multiple boxes.
In this case you shouldnt wrap anything in the select just something like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group" value="<?php echo $nomeA; ?>">I have a <?php echo $nomeA; ?><br>
```

within the for loop.

Good Luck
Narimm

Comment: i want to have checkbox so user can select multiple box right?

Comment: Yes Checkboxes allow a user to select more than 1

Answer (score 0):

```
echo'<input type ="checkbox" name = "'.$row['nomeA'].'"value = "'.$row['nomeA'].'" />'.$row['nomeA'].'<br />;
```

instead of :
     $nomeA = $row['nomeA'];
remove the select tag and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

just to complete my task, i will post what its need to get the values selected:

```
<?php
            session_start();
            $email = $_SESSION['email'];
            $nEnc = $_SESSION['nEnc'];
            $options = $_REQUEST['dispo'];
            echo("<p>$email</p>");
            echo("<p>$nEnc</p>");
            try
            {
                $host = "xxxx";
                $user ="xxxx";
                $password = "xxxx";
                $dbname = $user;
                $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                foreach($options as $name){
                    $nomeA = $name;
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO RegistoEnc VALUES ('$email',$nEnc,'$nomeA');";
                    echo("<p>$sql</p>");
                    $db->query($sql);
                };
                $db = null;
            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                echo("<p>ERROR: {$e->getMessage()}</p>");
            }
            echo "<br>Encomenda Criada!!<br>";
        ?>
```